# .replace and anchors

Tags: jquery, replace, anchor

I have an anchor like this in my website:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenNewWindow('/PhotoDetails.asp?ProductCode=ProductCode', 640, 480)" title="">
```

Using jQuery, how would it be possible to replace `javascript:OpenNewWindow('/PhotoDetails` with `/ProductDetails` and replace `', 640, 480)` with nothing?

I tried `.replace` but it's complicated since theres single quotes in the content.

Thanks.

Comment: I would abandon the inline JS and use a separate handler with variables.

Comment: @mblase75 - That would be the ideal solution, +1

Comment: @mblase75 The whole question is how do I get rid of the inline js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a regex guru, but here is a simple indexOf solution using the single quotes as boundaries.

http://jsfiddle.net/CWjV5/3

```
$('a').each( function() {
    var href = $(this).prop('href');
    href = href.substring(href.indexOf("'") + 1, href.lastIndexOf("'"));
    href = href.replace('Photo', 'Product');
    $(this).prop('href', href);
});;
```

Comment: But I have to replace the word Photo with the word Product

Comment: @user1090389 - woops, didn't notice that bit. Updated my answer.

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot just implement it like this, there are other anchors in my site. To target specifically which anchors I want to modify, I changed it to: `table.class1 tbody.class2 tr. class3 td.class4 a ` and it didn't work.

Comment: I have no idea what your html markup looks like so I can't say why or why not it would work. If you post your markup (in my fiddle would be nice) I can take a look.

Comment: Oh, I got it, my site runs jQuery 1.4.2, your script does not work with jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: @user1090389 - Change `prop` to `attr` if you are using jQuery <1.7